# Disable built-in behaviour of Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using a Google Map in my Android app, but it has some unwanted behaviour. When I tap the map, it shows two icons, that you can use to switch to the web-version.

When I first create the map, it looks like this:
[image: screenshot of first map]

When I tap it, it shows these two buttons:
[image]

I want to disable that, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        UiSettings ui = map.getUiSettings();
        ui.setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false)` to disable that.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/interactivity#toolbar